# How to disable or customize the PathPatternParser in WebContentInterceptor spring mvc xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-framework-beans

I am facing problem with pattern /**/abc in `WebContentInterceptor` in SpringFramework 5.3.23.

```
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'cacheMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PatternParseException: No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element
```

By default `WebContentInterceptor` use `PathPatternParser` which we can not make `null`.

I tried configuring `PathMatchConfigurer` to set path matcher as `AntPathMatcher` but as `PathPatternParser` is tightly coupled in `WebContentInterceptor` it is not solving the issue.

Comment: I don't see the problem, just construct the `WebContentInterceptor` and pass the `AntPathMatcher` in the constructor. You are already constructing it yourself, just use the proper constructor.

Comment: There are two properties in WebContentInterceptor 1- PathMatcher whose value by default is AntPathMatcher 2- PathPatternParser whose default value is new PathPatternParser(). How can we replace PathPatternParser with AntPathMatcher. They both are different.

Comment: Setting the `PathMatchConfigurer` doesn't do anything for the `WebContentInterceptor` which you configure yourself. You need to change this and not something else. Please show what you tried and please iclude the **full stacktrace**.